# Where you set path for golang or java in ubuntu?

Tags: bashrc, etc

In some tutorials path is set in ~/.profile however in some other tutorials they use etc/path or ~/.bashrc, can you explain whats the difference and how it works in linux.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the availability of the files and the order of their execution. Whenever you open a new shell, ~/.bashrc file is read. The ~/.profile file is read only when user logs in, but not when the user starts a new shell. So whether you set path in ~/.bashrc file or in ~/.profile file, it wouldn't make much difference. A good practice is to set it in ~/.bashrc file. 
Also, the ~/.profile file is read only when ~/.bash_login or ~/.bash_profile files are not available.